# Return JSONObject from server plugin in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I am attempting to create a server plugin in neo4j to make a specific query and wish to return, not one iterable, but two iterables of Node.

I saw that this is not possible according to the neo4j docs, so I tried to create an array of JSONObject from these arrays and then return it as server plugin result. But it seems that this does not work.

So I am asking if someone has already done such thing?

I have been told on [neo4j google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/neo4j) to use Gremlin, but have never use it before and think it is a bit complicated.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you are querying exactly and why you want two iterables.

Comment: I ended up merging the two arrays i want to return and then retrieve them separately in my code....
Problem resolved

Comment: Can you post your answer with some code, then accept it your self? For the sake of other people who have similar issues:)

Comment: see the answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i eventually got around the problem by merging the two lists i wanted to return before returning a unique list. Hence i could separate them in my python code, since i know where starts each one.

```
public class Ond extends ServerPlugin {

@PluginTarget(GraphDatabaseService.class)
public static Iterable<Node> getOnd(
        @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb,
        @Description("the airline's node ID") @Parameter(name = "id") int id) {

    List<Node> results= new ArrayList<Node>();

    String n4jQuery= "START al= node("+id+") match ond-[:operatedBy]->al, ond-[:origin]->orig, ond-[:destination]->dest RETURN orig, dest ;"; 

    ExecutionEngine engine= new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
    ExecutionResult result= engine.execute(n4jQuery);
    List<Node> orig= new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> dest= new ArrayList<Node>();

    //creating the lists i want to return
    //an outter loop over tables rows
    for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
    //an inner loop over the two columns : orig and dest
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> column : row.entrySet()) {

            String key = column.getKey();
            Node n = (Node) column.getValue();
            if(key.equals("dest")){
                dest.add(n);
            }else{
                orig.add(n);
            }
        }

    }

      //merging the two lists
    results.addAll(orig);
    results.addAll(dest);

      // orig elements are between indices 0 and size(results)/2 -1 
      //and dest element are between size(results)/2 and size(results)-1
    return results;
}
```

}

Hope it helps !!